# How do I include plotting symbol glyphs in a text annotation in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to include the glyph used in a scatter plot directly in a text annotation.

E.g.,  Suppose I have:

```
g <- g + geom_text(aes(x=14, y = 17, label="GOOD"))
```

where g is a scatter plot w/ a linear trend line, labeled by "GOOD" at (14,17). Instead of 
"GOOD", I'd like to have "X = GOOD" where X is a plotting glyph (e.g., a hollow triangle, circle etc.) used in the scatter plot. This way I can dispense w/ the legend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably do it by plotting a single point of the right type using `annotate()`, with the text you have above next to it as a separate `annotate()`.

Personally, though, it sounds like you're trying to make what they used to call a camera-ready image. In that case, I'd recommend exporting to PDF and using something like Inkspace to custom-create your in-graph labels. It'll be simpler and you have a lot more flexibility, plus a WYSIWYG interface.

Comment: Thanks Harlan and Richie - that's what I ended up doing and it worked quite well.

Answer (score 2):

To expand upon Harlan's answer, here's a plot of the car's dataset

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point()
```

You need to add two annotations, and the trick is to set the horizontal justification of the text to make the positions line up.

```
x <- 4
y <- 30
p + annotate("point", x, y) + annotate("text", x, y, label = " = GOOD", hjust = 0)
```

The alternative is to use `opts(legend.position = ??)` to place your legend inside the plot, which has much the same effect.